# how to fill NAN by element before them?

Tags: pandas

I have a data fram in one of the  columns there are NAN between two elements. how I can fill this NAN by an element before them?

Df['col1]:

```
                                             A
                                              NaN
                                             NaN
                                            NaN
                                              B
                                             NaN
                                             NaN
                                            NaN
```

output:

```
                                             A
                                             A
                                            A
                                            A
                                              B
                                            B
                                             B
                                           B
```

Comment: Df['col1].ffill()

Comment: pls feel free to comment if you think that the question is wrongly closed **:)**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the fillna method, specified as a forward-fill:

```
df.fillna(method='ffill')
```